# blazy.js angular directives not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hi guys i've been stuck with this i created a directive using [blazy](http://dinbror.dk/blazy/)

but it seems that it's not working on ng-repeat here is my code in the directive

```
 'use strict';

angular.module('angularExerciseApp')
  .directive('lazyLoader', function() {
    return {
      scope: { image: '=imageData' },
      template:'<img class="b-lazy" data-blazy="{{image.largeImg}}" data-blazy-small="{{image.smallImg}}"  alt="alt-text" />',
      restrict: 'EA',

      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var bLazy = new Blazy({
              src: 'data-blazy' ,
              breakpoints: [{
                  width: 420 // Max-width
                      , src: 'data-blazy-small'
              }]

          });
      }
    };
  });
```

and on my html tag im calling the directives this way
the result output was this

```
<div lazy-loader="" ng-repeat="image in imageLists" image-data="image" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
           <img class="b-lazy" data-blazy="assets/images/big-bear2.jpg" data-blazy-small="assets/images/bear-small1.jpg" alt="alt-text">
</div>
```

what am i doing wrong here?can you guys help on this .thanks and have a good day

here is the [plunker url](http://plnkr.co/edit/8yvOcuQ7dvHmKZ4BbU6S?p=preview)

Comment: If anyone is looking for the fix still, you need to call revalidate() on the bLazy variable